# SQL express connection string FOR vb6

Tags: sql-server, vb6, connection-string

Need to connect SQL server 2005 WITH vb6.

i have below code..

i have to change Username and password to open the software. 
but it is in windows authentication to open,

Public Sub OpenConn()

```
If Cn.State = 1 Then Cn.Close
'sql 2000 sql authentication
Cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb; Data Source=Guru;Initial Catalog=eIntelliCabs;User Id=w[enter image description here][1]indowsusername;Password=windowsloginpassword;"
'sql 2005 /2008 express windows authetication
'Cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=maity;Initial Catalog=eIntelliCabs;User Id=sa;Password=123;"    
Cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
Cn.Open
```

Kindly help me with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use SQL Authentication try:

```
Cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=ServerName\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=c:\YourPath\mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;"
```

To use Trusted Security (windows authentication) try:

```
Cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=ServerName\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=c:\YourPath\mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

For more information checkout [Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Comment: Thanks a lot fred, i have used windows authentication and changed accordingly to my computer.